# .htaccess in subdir gets ignored by Wordpress' own .htaccess in /

Tags: apache-http-server, wordpress, htaccess

I have a Wordpress installation on the root of an apache (I.E. on `/`) and WP wrote this custom .htaccess:
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>`

Now I need to hide a single php script, let's say in `/scritps/hello.php`, I tried a .htaccess in `scripts` with:
`<files hello.php>

 Order allow,deny

 Deny from all

</files>`

But it gets overriden by WP's .htaccess, and hello.php is shown anyway. ( **I know this because moving the `scripts` directory out of WP to another vhost on my local environment makes it work** ).

I want to hide this php file on the live site because it should only be called by cron from the command line, and I can't put the file outside the apache root because that's all I have FTP access to.
And no, I don't have SSH access, someone else's going to set the cron job.

Comment: You might have more luck on the WordPress StackExchange.

Comment: @Teknophilia This is an Apache issue rather than a wordpress issue

Comment: Is `mod_access` definitely loaded in apache (the module that processes allow/deny statements), and `AllowOverrides +Limit` is enabled in `httpd.conf`, allowing you to change access permissions in .htaccess?

Comment: Yes both are true, as this works if the file and the .htaccess are moved to a different vhost that doesn't have Wordpress but is still under the same Apache

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't `Order Deny, Allow` be correct to hide the file?